# JAVA 8 - Lambda and Streams to replace ExecutorService

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to execute below code using parallel streams and lambda since it is a lot cleaner code?
I am not sure how to go through it.

```
public static NavigableSet<String> getDistinctNavigableLowerCaseMakeNames(Loader loader) {
    String[] regions = {Japan, Germany, USA};
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(regions.length);

    Set<Make> unique = new HashSet<>();
    for (Region region : regions) {
        EXECUTOR.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                List<Make> regionMakes = getVehicleMakesByRegion(region); //provides all the vehicles based on the region
                    unique.addAll(regionMakes);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
    }
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(ie);
    }

   return unique;
}
```

Make is a class consisting of final variables id, region and name.

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes. You've dumped a bunch of complex code and basically asked "please rewrite this using lambdas and Streams".  If you want help it is up to you to make it easy for others to help you, and that means explaining what your code does, and showing your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Your original code is broken. You are concurrently modifying a `HashSet`, which is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this, it looks a little shorter :)

```
 String[] regionArray = {"Japan", "Germany", "USA"};
 List<String> regions = Arrays.asList(regionArray);
 return regions
        .parallelStream()
        .flatMap(r -> loader.getVehicleMakesByRegion(r).stream())
        .map(m->m.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ConcurrentSkipListSet::new));
```

Remember to add a comment to the Loader interface specifying that implementation MUST be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you want to find unique makes for a list of regions. If that's the case then:

```
Arrays.stream("Japan", "Germany", "USA").parallel()
    .map(loader::getVehicleMakesByRegion)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(Make::getName)
    .distinct()
    ...
```

If `Make.equals` exists then you could move `distinct` before the `getName`. It also may make sense to change `getVehicleByRegion` to return a `Stream<Make>`.